# Wrong error with EF Code First Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I made many changes to a database in development, using AddMigration along the way to update the database.
Now, I'm ready to go to production. 
I pulled down the production version, and attempted to use Update-Database to bring it ☆n sync.
However, when I attempt to, I get:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot find the object "dbo.AspNetUsers" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Thing is, I know this table exists, so that can't be THE error. 
Any idea what should be done?

Comment: Are you sure it's pointing at the correct database?

Answer (score 0):

PEBCAK.
When I checked the connection strings again, I was pointing to a fresh db, not the staged version.